# Drupal7: How unset a label from exposed filter

Tags: php, drupal-7

How can I unset label from a exposed filter in a custom module? (form_alter)

HTML:

```
...
<form action="/location-list" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-zoekresultaten-geolocation-zoekresultaten" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <div>
        <div class="views-exposed-form">
        <div class="views-exposed-widgets clearfix">
        <div id="edit-distance-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-filter-distance">
        <div class="views-widget">
        <div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-distance-postal-code">
        <label for="edit-distance-postal-code">Postcode </label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-distance-postal-code" name="distance[postal_code]" value="" size="60" maxlength="16" class="form-text" />
    </div>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change field using form_alter and set '#title_display' => 'invisible' inside  your field?
[Form api reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#title_display)